# How to set APM of a hard drive in Linux command line?

Tags: linux, external-hard-drive, raspberry-pi, power-management

Strange things are happening in my system... I have a Raspberry Pi 4 with Raspberry OS Lite and some external WD HDDs atached to the USB port. I want to change the hard drive APM value so that I can control when it spins down. Sometimes I want it to stay fully ON (APM:254) and sometimes spin down after a while (APM:127).

To set the APM value I tried the following command:

```
sudo smartctl -s apm,254 /dev/sdb
```

It is working fine, and I got this output:

```
=== START OF ENABLE/DISABLE COMMANDS SECTION ===
APM set to level 254 (maximum performance)
```

Now, if I access this HDD regularly the APM value remains to 254. But if is no disk activity for a while, the disk spins down (what !?) and when it came back it has APM = 127. It is acting like it has a lower APM value, not the one that I set it (254) even if it is correctly displayed.

What do you think is wrong ? Could it be another OS function that override my manual setting ? How can I set it and make it remain like that until I change it ? In Windows, when I send that ATA command to change the APM value to 254, it stays like that until I restart the computer, and the disk never spins down...